# Apply a vectorized function to array numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to apply a function to an array, but when I call it, it generates an error since the function only enters the first component of the array

```
import numpy as np

def fObjetivo(x):
    print(x)
    return x[0] + x[1] + x[2]

fObjetivo = np.vectorize(fObjetivo)

a = np.array([1,2,3])

print(fObjetivo(a))
```

where are the error?

Comment: Why did you call `vectorize` on this thing at all?

Comment: Normally `vectorize` passes a scalar to your function.  To pass something else you need to use the `signature` parameter.  But can't you just pass `a` to the original `fObjectivo`?  Why do you think you need `vectorize`?

Comment: This is a simple example, the complete program should execute much more complex functions that I want to enter, so I look for how I can optimize them to the maximum

Comment: Thanks  hpaulj¡¡

Comment: Note: `numpy.vectorize` is for convenience, not performance. It is essentially a Python for loop underneath the hood

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga you have a good point, there is not much information about vectorized functions and in what you read it they say they are faster, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case, array a is vectorized and sent one element at a time. Declare a as 2D array[:,3] then send as a[0]. it may work.